# Find a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$..

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a $2 × 2$ matrix and $I$ be the identity matrix. Assume that the null spaces of $A − 4I$
and $A − I$ respectively are spanned by
$\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}$
and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$
respectively. Find a matrix $B$ such that
$B^2 = A$.

How to approach this problem? Any hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly,4,1 are eigenvalue of A,.so A can be diagonalizable, so, A=PDP⁻¹, some nonsingular P,,,,

Comment: For B ,,just take B= PCP⁻¹,,,where C is 2×2 diagonal matrix with diagonal entries 2,1

Comment: Thanks @Subhajit

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ are eignevectors of $A$ with eigenvalues 4 and 1, respectively. Now, we just need to make a matrix $B$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\pm 2$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\pm 1$. I'll leave the rest to you, good luck (:

Comment: All you explained i know already. But i didn't find such matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $A \dbinom{3}{2} = 4 \dbinom{3}{2}$ and that $A \dbinom{1}{1} = \dbinom{1}{1}$. So, if we define $P := \bigg( \begin{matrix} 3&1\\2&1 \end{matrix} \bigg)$ then
$$P^{-1}AP \dbinom{1}{0} = \dbinom{4}{0} \textrm{ and } P^{-1}AP \dbinom{0}{1} = \dbinom{0}{1},$$
that is, $P^{-1}AP = \bigg( \begin{matrix} 4&0\\0&1 \end{matrix} \bigg)$. Now, all that you need is a matrix $B$ such that $(P^{-1}BP)^2 = P^{-1}AP$.